# Ethernet bonding round-robin not work when 1st interface down

Tags: rhel, ethernet, bonding

I'm trying to understand the bonding mode=0 (load balancing round-robin). Using eth0 & eth1, I created bond0 interface as the configuration below :

```
root@test-env1:~# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
USERCTL=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.57.91
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.57.1
BONDING_OPTS="mode=0 miimon=100"
root@test-env1:~#
root@test-env1:~# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
root@test-env1:~# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
root@test-env1:~#
```

Bonding interface established successfully :

```
root@test-env1:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 100
Down Delay (ms): 100

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:30:0d:9e
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:a0:fc:9e
Slave queue ID: 0
root@test-env1:~#
```

Then I tried to disconnect the cable of eth0, ping test reported that the IP became unreachable. I know that kind of failover scenario will definitely works with mode=1 (active-backup).

**Update : status of bond after eth0 plugged

```
root@test-env1:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:30:0d:9e
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:a0:fc:9e
Slave queue ID: 0
root@test-env1:~#
```

It also strange that when I rebooted the server with eth0 remain unplugged, bond interface didn't UP at all. Although the configuration still have eth1 as active/connected interface.

[Bonding documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt) said that balance-rr or mode 0 provides load balancing and fault tolerance. I just curious the know what kind of fault tolerance that provided by bonding mode=0.

```
mode

    Specifies one of the bonding policies. The default is
    balance-rr (round robin).  Possible values are:

    balance-rr or 0

        Round-robin policy: Transmit packets in sequential
        order from the first available slave through the
        last.  This mode provides load balancing and fault
        tolerance.
```

Could someone help me figure it out whether the bond mode=0 requires both interface to be active? If yes, then how mode=0 provides the fault tolerance?

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: when you unplugged eth0, its status went to down in `/proc/net/bonding/bond0`, so we're sure the system noticed it went away?

Comment: Yes  MII Status: down

Comment: What is the output in your syslog when you unplug one cable ?

Comment: How do you configure your switch? In bonding documentation: "The balance-rr, balance-xor and broadcast modes generally require that the switch have the appropriate ports grouped together. The nomenclature for such a group differs between switches, it may be called an “etherchannel” (as in the Cisco example, above), a “trunk group” or some other similar variation."

Comment: If you switch is configured correctly, a way to debug is: `echo 'module bonding +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control` ...

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Make your comment an answer!

Answer (score 1):

How do you configure your switch?

In bonding documentation:

*"The balance-rr, balance-xor and broadcast modes generally require that the switch have the appropriate ports grouped together. The nomenclature for such a group differs between switches, it may be called an “etherchannel” (as in the Cisco example, above), a “trunk group” or some other similar variation."*